# what is the right usage of _extra_files arg in torch.jit.save

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, torchscript

one option I tried is pickling vocab and saving with extrafiles arg

```py
import torch
import pickle

class Vocab(object):
    pass

vocab = Vocab()
pickle.dump(open('path/to/vocab.pkl','w'))

m = torch.jit.ScriptModule()

## I am not sure about the usage of this arg, the docs didn't help me
extra_files = torch._C.ExtraFilesMap()
extra_files['vocab.pkl'] = 'path/to/vocab.pkl'
# I also tried  pickle.dumps(vocab), and directly vocab

torch.jit.save(m, 'scriptmodule.pt', _extra_files=extra_files)

## Load with extra files.
files = {'vocab.pkl': ''}
torch.jit.load('scriptmodule.pt', _extra_files = files)
```

this gives

```
TypeError: import_ir_module(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: Callable[[List[str]], torch._C.ScriptModule], arg1: str, arg2: object, arg3: torch._C.ExtraFilesMap) -> None
```

other option is obviously to load the pickle separately, but I was looking for single file option.

it would be nice if one could just add vocab to to the torchscript ... it would also be nice to know if there is some reason for not doing this that I am obviously not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the documentation for `torch.jit.load` is incorrect. You need to create an ExtraFilesmap() object to load the saved files.

The following is an example of how I got things to work:
Step 1: Save model

```
extra_files = torch._C.ExtraFilesMap()
extra_files['foo.txt'] = 'bar'
traced_script_module.save(serialized_model_path, _extra_files=extra_files)
```

Step 2: Load model

```
files = torch._C.ExtraFilesMap()
files['foo.txt'] = ''
loaded_model = torch.jit.load(serialized_model_path, _extra_files=files)
print(files)
```

Comment: Now when I look at the error, at least the error makes sense, it asking for arg type `torch._C.ExtraFilesMap()` and not a python dict

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `vocab` is a supported type, you could add it to the model as a [TorchScript attribute](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#module-attributes) to store it alongside the model in 1 file (so you won't have to deal with `_extra_files`).

Then your loading code becomes

```py
torch.jit.load('scriptmodule.pt')
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem located in torch.jit.load .
try check your map_location